# Code reuse in non-compiled project

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a non-compiled web app which has several pages that all have similar functionality. If I compile the code it's easy to share classes between files, but I'm having trouble achieving the same without compiling. If I have an XmlRequest.cs file, how do I access its class from Compare.aspx.cs?

Comment: What are you avoiding recompilation?

Comment: Try taking the code you want to share and compiling it into a DLL, then all you need to do is reference the DLL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add XmlRequest.cs to a folder named [App_Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23.aspx), it will be available throughout your webapp.